# How to set a work item state while creating or updating work item in Azure Devops Rest API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, workitem

I have been working to create an API which programatically creates/updates work item in Azure Devops. I have been able to create a work item and populate almost all fields. I have problem with setting the state.

When I am creating a POST request to Azure Devops rest api with any state name like "Active", "Closed", "Rejected", it throws a 400 Bad Request error.

I don't know if I am missing anything or if there something wrong with the way I am trying to set the value.

```
{
  "op" : "add", 
  "path": "/fields/System.State", 
  "value"="Active",
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem and hence I am answering it here.

I was getting a 400 Bad Request error whenever I tried Creating an Item and Setting the state in the same call. I debugged the code and caught the exception. I found out that, there are some validation rules for some of the fields. State is one of them.

The rule for System.State field is, whenever a Work Item is created it takes its configured default value. ( In my case it was "Proposed", in your case it could be "New"). If you try altering the value at the time of work item creation, it throws a 400 Bad Request.

What should I do if I have to Create a Work Item with a specific State?

As of now, the solution that I have found out is to make two calls. One for Work Item Creation and another for Changing the state of the work item to desired state.

```
CreateWorkItem()
{
 var result = await _client.Post(url, jsonData);
 var result2 = await _client.Put(result.id, jsonData); // or maybe just the state
 return Ok(result2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the example here: [Update a field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#update-a-field)

You have to use `"value":"Active"` in the request body.

```
[
  {
      "op" : "add", 
      "path": "/fields/System.State", 
      "value": "Active"
   }
]
```

Comment: I am using the same thing. Apparently, the problem is only with create, for any update operation, this works fine.

Comment: There is no explanation or sample code of how to use "value":"Active" in the request body thus the downvote